# SharePoint 2010 RTM to SP1 or SP2?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Currently we are running on SharePoint 2010 RTM version and we need to be upgrade to SP2.

Can Anyone suggests me please
SharePoint 2010 RTM to SP1 then SP2? how what is the process for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install SP2 bypassing previous updates. You'll then want to install the latest CU for security purposes.